# Как отобрать пропуски значений чисел по порядку в массиве?

Tags: php, массивы, циклы

```
array(3000) {
  [0]=>
  int(100)
  [1]=>
  int(101)
  [2]=>
  int(102)
  [3]=>
  int(103)
  [4]=>
  int(105)
  [5]=>
  int(108)
  .....
}
```

Есть массив такого вида. Он содержит числа меньшего к большему. Но есть пропуски, как отобрать все числа, которые пропущены в отдельный массив?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
// исходный массив
$ar = [1,2,3,5];
// массив всех чисел от минимального до максимально в массиве
$range = range(min($ar), max($ar), 1);
// array_diff даст отсутствующие элементы
print_r(array_diff($range, $ar));
```

Comment: Ау, и что не так?

Comment: скажите, а если массив идет наоборот, от большего к меньшему?

Comment: @Dizzy221 а какая разница, минимум все равно меньше всех, а максимум...

Comment: $ar = [90,89,88,84,83];

$range = range(min($ar), max($ar)-min($ar), 1);

echo '<pre>';
print_r(array_diff($range, $ar));
echo '</pre>';

он выдает все числа..

Comment: Голова моя садовая :) поправил, там максимум, а не кол-во во втором параметре

Comment: теперь все работает, благодарю за оперативную правку)